# Problems displaying uploaded images in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I made a simple little image upload page in my Symfony project following [these docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).  The file uploads work fine after setting the permissions to the destination directory to 777.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to display the uploaded images in a gallery, they won't display, and Apache 2 gives me a 'not found' error.

The web path of the images is dynamically generated by my `GalleryImage` entity:

```
public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/gallery';
}
```

In my view (twig), I attempt to display them with the following:

```
<a href="{{ image.webPath }}" data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="{{ asset(image.webPath) }}" class="gallery-thumb"></a>
```

Which generates markup that looks like:

```
<a href="/home/kevin/www/diva/src/MajorProductions/SewingDiva/SiteBundle/Entity/../../../../../web/uploads/gallery/d15728da272656a4ab0e670f589ee033e43494d6.jpeg" data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="/home/kevin/www/diva/src/MajorProductions/SewingDiva/SiteBundle/Entity/../../../../../web/uploads/gallery/d15728da272656a4ab0e670f589ee033e43494d6.jpeg" class="gallery-thumb"></a>
```

But, when I attempt to access them, it tells me:

> The requested URL /home/kevin/www/diva/web/uploads/gallery/d15728da272656a4ab0e670f589ee033e43494d6.jpeg was not found on this server

Even though, again, the destination directory has 777 for its permissions, and I can *see* the images there in the file system.

Any ideas why it's telling me my images can't be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this works for me:

```
<a href="{{ asset('uploads/gallery/') }}{{image.path}}" data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="{{ asset('uploads/gallery/') }}{{image.path}}" class="gallery-thumb"></a>
```