# symfony server running locally on PC (MAMP) does not display images

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, mime-types

I am running a symfony server on my local PC machine using MAMP for my stack.
Everything seems to work fine except the images won't load in the views. If I try navigating to the image directly, the browser (Chrome and Firefox) downloads the images instead of displaying them. This leads me to believe I have MIME type issues, but I am not sure how to check what the symfony server is trying to do.

I am also seeing a couple console warnings when I try to load css files, that look like this is Chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type >application/x-gzip: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/styles.css"

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please give example of how you display the image in your html or css style code ?

Comment: @osify I am just using an img tag <img class="logo-icon" src="{{ asset('images/aquanote-logo.png') }}"> and the image itself is in the web/images directory.   The image is being served as the server is responding with a 200, but somehow it looks like it puts the header of the response at the top of the image stream, thus corrupting the .png file itself.  I found another question that seems to be exactly the same here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504098/images-not-loading-in-symfony-2-8)

Comment: Can you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920032/problems-displaying-uploaded-images-in-symfony-2

And if not what is the full link that symphony generate for the image, is it: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/aquanote-logo.png"? It seems not a correct apache host url

Comment: Yes, that is the correct path: http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/aquanote-logo.png  I agree that it seems like an apache issue, but not sure how to solve for it. Using the same apache to serve other non-symfony sites works fine, it seems to only affect images served by the symfony web server.

Comment: If I use the direct link to the image, it downloads the file, but it seems to insert the http response header into the body of the file, so opening the file, I see something like this at the top. > HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 226415